# Printing all paths from root to leaf

Tags: rust, binary-tree

I have a binary tree structure, and I am trying to print all the paths from root to leaf nodes using the `fmt::Display` trait in Rust.

For example, for the following tree:

```
    a
   / \
  b   e
 / \
c   d
```

I want an output something like the following.

```
a -> b -> c -> Nil
a -> b -> c -> Nil
a -> b -> d -> Nil
a -> b -> d -> Nil
a -> e -> Nil
a -> e -> Nil
```

This is what I have:

```
use std::fmt;

enum Node {
    Nil,
    Data(String, Box<Node>, Box<Node>),
}

impl fmt::Display for Node {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Node::Nil => write!(f, "Nil"),
            Node::Data(data, left, right) => write!(f, "{} -> {} , {}", data, *left, *right),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tree = Node::Data(
        String::from("a"),
        Box::new(Node::Data(
            String::from("b"),
            Box::new(Node::Data(
                String::from("c"),
                Box::new(Node::Nil),
                Box::new(Node::Nil),
            )),
            Box::new(Node::Data(
                String::from("d"),
                Box::new(Node::Nil),
                Box::new(Node::Nil),
            )),
        )),
        Box::new(Node::Data(
            String::from("e"),
            Box::new(Node::Nil),
            Box::new(Node::Nil),
        )),
    );

    println!("{}", tree);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=76af35929c56ee8c583b019a9380a9f4

I am not sure if it is possible to pass the parent node's information to the child nodes.

Answer (score 2):

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Clone)]
enum Node {
    Nil,
    Data(String, Box<Node>, Box<Node>),
}


impl Node {
    fn fmt_tree(&self, path: &mut Vec<Node>) {
        match self {
            Node::Nil => {
                for node in path {
                    print!("{} -> ", node);
                }
                println!("{}", self);
            },
            Node::Data(_, left, right) => {
                path.push(self.clone());
                left.fmt_tree(path);
                right.fmt_tree(path);
                path.pop();
            },
        }
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Node {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Node::Nil => write!(f, "Nil"),
            Node::Data(s, _, _) => write!(f, "{}", s)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {

    let tree = Node::Data(String::from("a"),
                            Box::new(Node::Data(String::from("b"),
                                        Box::new(Node::Data(String::from("c"),
                                                    Box::new(Node::Nil), Box::new(Node::Nil))),
                                        Box::new(Node::Data(String::from("d"),
                                                    Box::new(Node::Nil), Box::new(Node::Nil))))),
                            Box::new(Node::Data(String::from("e"),
                                        Box::new(Node::Nil), Box::new(Node::Nil))));

    tree.fmt_tree(&mut Vec::new());
}
```

prints:

```
a -> b -> c -> Nil
a -> b -> c -> Nil
a -> b -> d -> Nil
a -> b -> d -> Nil
a -> e -> Nil
a -> e -> Nil
```

exactly, using a simple recursive depth-first binary tree search (in `fmt_tree`)

Comment: Not bad! I noticed [you don't need `Clone` if you can use a reference](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=43a73c17f287d5f4748b3dcf15a4c26f). You could also call `fmt_tree` from inside `Display` instead of the other way around, and then you don't have to expose the internals.

Comment: This works! I would implement a sort of a to_string function, and then use it inside println! I, however, was looking if there is a proper way to do this recursively with fmt::Display itself.

Comment: Also, stock `&String` in this case make more sense cause you don't have to match self for the final printing.